# Contract not showing the name, symbol, and supply

Tags: tokens, etherscan, ropsten, smart-contract-wallets

I am not able to see the name, symbol, and supply on the smart contract at ropsten.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyToken{
address public minter;
mapping(address => uint) public balance;
string public name;
string public symbol;
uint256 public totalSupply;
uint8 public decimals;
event Sent( address from, address to,  uint amount);

constructor () {
minter = msg.sender; 
name = "COOP";
symbol= "COP";
totalSupply= 100 * 1000;
decimals= 18;


}

function mint(address recieve, uint amount) public {
    require(msg.sender == minter);
    balance[recieve] += amount;
}

function send(address reciever, uint amount) public {
    require(amount <= balance [msg.sender], "insuffient funds");
    balance[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balance[reciever] += amount;
    emit Sent(msg.sender, reciever,amount);
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean with *I am not able to see the name, symbol, and supply*? They are public so you should be able to query them.

Answer (score 0):

This is because strings have to be read from the memory storage;

Declared like this

```
string  public symbol;
string  public name;
```

in a function or constructor as well

```
function setMyString(string memory myString) public {
   symbol = myString;
}
```

However, If your creating a token you should look at the ERC20 Standard to make sure you follow it and your token can be recognise by wallet and other contract.

To make an ERC20 you Must follow the standard. Look at Open Zeppelin Library that will provide you with a pre-made contract that you can reuse and customize.

Comment: When I declare the string it give me error.

Comment: I added the public statement. Try if this was your error. Giving error is meaningless unless you have an actual error message.

Comment: If you get an error it's probably not from that declaration.

Comment: the declaration is an error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: At the top level declaration your right i removed the memory. Use memory only in the functions

Comment: Yes I did that but the token info is still not available

Comment: available where?

Comment: I am not able to see the token info at etherscan test network

Comment: I feel something wrong in my code that dont allow me to see the info.

Comment: I would say take a look at the Open Zeppelin Library. You don't need to write the ERC20 token contract. If you do, look for the ERC20 Standard and understand it.